# Tkinter Geometry Return to Normal

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, geometry, fullscreen

I have a tkinter window which I am able to make fullscreen, using `geometry(width+height)` and `overrideredirect(True)`, but now when I return the window back to a normal size and execute the command `overrideredirect(False)`, I cannot seem to get the window to automatically follow the size of the widgets inside it, as it would do had I not changed the size. Do you know any way which I could return the window to automatically following the size of the widgets again? Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the geometry with a value of `""` to get it to reset itself to its natural size.

Tkinter is based on tk, and the [tk docs](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.htm#M28) say this on the matter:

> If newGeometry is specified as an empty string then any existing
>   user-specified geometry for window is cancelled, and the window will
>   revert to the size requested internally by its widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [`winfo_reqwidth/reqheight()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_reqwidth-method) methods. These return the required width and height for all the widgets that are children of the widget they're called on. Just plug those into the `geometry()` method the same way you did to go fullscreen on your restore function, like this:

```
def fullscreen():
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.geometry('{0}x{1}+0+0'.format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))

def restore():
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.geometry('{0}x{1}'.format(root.winfo_reqwidth(), root.winfo_reqheight()))

root = Tk()

Button(root, text='Full Screen', command=fullscreen).pack()
Button(root, text='Restore', command=restore).pack()

root.mainloop()
```