# With Tkinter, how to position a dialog box at initiation OR how to auto-resize a window after geometry is set?

Tags: python, encryption, tkinter, resize, position

**Disclaimer:** In all likelihood this could very well be an XY problem, I'd appreciate if you would point me to the correct direction.

**Goal:** I have a file that I'd like tkinter to read and then create widgets dynamically based on the file contents.  **I want the window to always open centered at my cursor.**

For the sake of MCVE let's consider a plain text file that reads:

```
Madness?
This
IS
T K I N T E R
```

And tkinter should create 4 label widgets, with the main window resized to fit.  That's very simple... *until the file is encrypted.*  Before I can read the encrypted file, I need to `askstring()` for a password first (MCVE: let's also assume we're only asking for the `key` here).

**My issues:**

1. The `askstring` Dialog is always at a default position.  I know it's supposed to be relative to the parent (root)...
2. But I can't set `geometry()` before I create the widgets or else it won't resize to the widgets...
3. And I can't pre-determine the size required for `geometry()` since I can't open the file without the password (key)...

Here's a MCVE sample of my most successful attempt:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # side note: If I don't withdraw() the root first, the dialog ends up behind the root
        # and I couldn't find a way to get around this.
        self.withdraw()
        self.create_widgets()

        # Attempt: I tried doing this instead of self.create_widgets():
            # self.reposition()
            # self.after(ms=1,func=self.create_widgets)
        # The dialog is positioned correctly, but the window size doesn't resize

        self.deiconify()

        # I have to do the reposition AFTER mainloop or else the window size becomes 1x1
        self.after(ms=1, func=self.reposition)
        self.mainloop()

    def get_key(self):
        return askstring('Locked','Enter Key', show='*', parent=self)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.lbls = []
        with open('test2.txt', 'rb') as file:
            encrypted = file.read()
        key = self.get_key()
        suite = Fernet(key)
        self.data = suite.decrypt(encrypted).decode('utf-8')
        for i in self.data.split('\n'):
            self.lbls.append(tk.Label(self, text=i.strip()))
            self.lbls[-1].pack()

    def reposition(self):
        width, height = self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()
        self.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{self.winfo_pointerx()-int(width/2)}+{self.winfo_pointery()-int(height/2)}')

gui = GUI()
```

Which achieves (that I can live with):

- ✓ Correct size based on file content
- ✓ Root positioned at center of cursor
- ⨯ Prompts for key at center of cursor

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to perform an auto-resize on the root again based on the widgets function similar to `pack_propagate()` after `geometry()` is set? It seems once `geometry()` is set the root won't propagate no more.
2. If not, how can I manually resize it in code? I tried retrieving the total heights of the widgets `height = sum([i.winfo_reqheight() for i in self.lbls])` but `height` just becomes `0`.  But when I `print(self.lbls[-1].winfo_reqheight())` in the `self.create_widgets()` it returns `26` each, and they actually print *after* my `self.reposition()` call, which is weird.
3. Failing that, is it possible to position the `askstring()` dialog prior to the the widgets being created?

I'm stumped.  I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way but I'm not sure what is the correct way to handle this situation to break the cycle of dependency.

---

To help with reproducing here's the encrypted string as well as the key:

Data:

```
gAAAAABb2z3y-Kva7bdgMEbvnqGGRRJc9ZMrt8oc092_fuxSK1x4qlP72aVy13xR-jQV1vLD7NQdOTT6YBI17pGYpUZiFpIOQGih9jYsd-u1EPUeV2iqPLG7wYcNxYq-u4Z4phkHllvP
```

Key:

```
SecretKeyAnyhowGoWatchDareDevilS3ItsAmazing=
```

Edit: Based on [@BryanOakley's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853575/tkinter-geometry-return-to-normal) I can invoke `self.geometry("")` to reset, however it goes back to the native `200x200` size, and still doesn't propragate the widgets.

Comment: You can set up a function to resize window based on widgets inside of it to be run directly after all widgets have been updated. Should be simple enough.

Comment: @Mike-SMT could you point me to the right direction? I did search for that but all the questions involve resizing the widgets based on window size, not the window itself based on widgets.

Comment: Well if you do not tell the window to be a specific size it will automatically change size to fit the widgets. But let me see what I can work up with your code. Just finished installing 5 libraries just to be able to use Fernet :D

Comment: When you say you want the window to open centered at your cursor do you mean you want the windows top left corner to open at cursor or you want the center of the window on your cursor?

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thank you for looking into this with me.  Center on my cursor - which is what my `self.reposition()` method is currently doing, but for the main window only, not the dialog.

Comment: Well when I run the program it creates the window at the mouse and it is sized to the widgets. So I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, the dialog is centered for you as well? My dialog is always opening at top left corner.

Comment: Yep it centers for me no matter where my mouse is when I click on the ok button. What OS are you on and was version of Python?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit, Python 3.7.

Comment: Try going back to the last release of 3.6. You might be using one of the beta versions of 3.7 and that has been known to have some issues. I am currently using 3.6.2.

Comment: `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`, I don't think it's a beta version... but I have an environment with 3.6.3 I believe, I'll give that a try.  Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Let me know if that works for you. I am curious if there is a 3.7 issue that needs to be reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a dozens more tries I think I got it working, here are the relevant parts I modified:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.withdraw()

    # reposition the window first...
    self.reposition()

    # For some reason I can't seem to figure out, 
    # without the .after(ms=1) the dialog still goes to my top left corner
    self.after(ms=1, func=self.do_stuff)
    self.mainloop()

# wrap these functions to be called by .after()
def do_stuff(self):
    self.create_widgets()
    self.deiconify()

def reposition(self):
    width, height = self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()
    self.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{self.winfo_pointerx()-int(width/2)}+{self.winfo_pointery()-int(height/2)}')

    # reset the geometry per @BryanOakley's answer in the linked thread
    # Seems it resets the width/height but still retains the x/y
    self.geometry("")
```

It would appear [@BryanOakley have answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853575/tkinter-geometry-return-to-normal) for all things tkinter.

I'm still waiting to see if there will be others chiming in on the subject and will be happy to accept your answer to provide some clarity on the subject.